# Issue in jmeter with adopopenjdk 8

Tags: jmeter, adoptopenjdk

I am trying to execute one jar having few parameter as well in apache-jmeter-5.1.1. I am running Thread Plan -> OS Process Sampler. But getting below error always :

**Response message: Exception occurred whilst executing system call: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java -jar /User/wasim/Desktop/My_Jar/RunTask.jar " (in directory "/User/wasim/Desktop/jMeter/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin"): error=2, No such file or directory**

I tried to run jar directly and with full path.
I have passed java_home as parameter as well.

This is the request in jmeter interface :

**Working Directory: /User/wasim/Desktop/jMeter/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin
Environment: {JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home}
Executing: java -jar /User/wasim/Desktop/My_Jar/RunTask.jar update 20180401**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the issue after doing below changes :

In command section put only "java"
then put all your command after java into Command parameter section like below :

-jar

RunTask.jar

update

20180401

Make sure all remaining command should be in separate line without any space in the end.

Happy learning.